# Trouble switching views, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, uiview

In my `UIViewController` class, i

```
-(void)switchToPuzzle2:(id)sender {

     p2 = [Puzzle2 new]; // p2 is a UIView

    [p1 addSubview:p2];  //p1 is UIView currently showing
    [p1 removeFromSuperview];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I would effectively like to put `p2` on top of `p1`, or in place of `p1`.

This, however does (visibly) nothing.

Method is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the code that you have above, you are adding P2 to P1, then removing P1, thereby removing both from P1's superView.

If you are trying to switch the two, add P2 to P1's superview, then remove P1.  i.e.

```
[p1.superView addSubview: p2];
[p1 removeFromSuperview];
```

Also, do not call viewDidLoad.  That will probably nullify everything that you are doing.  Especially if you are loading from a Nib

Good luck

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you

Comment: Edited my answer, you should remove [super viewDidLoad]  that will probably nullify everything that you did if you are loading from a nib.  Still not good practice to do it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

[p1 removeFromSuperview];

just removes p1 form its own superview. As you just added p2 as a subview of p1, you remove both the views.

You can do something like

```
[[p1 superview] addSubview:p2];
```

And then if you want to remove p1 and not let it under p2

```
[p1 removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as timthetoolman and MatLecu mention, your example will have removed both views.  Yet, you say that p2 is still not visible given the solution?

My suggestion is to ensure that the frame is sized properly such that you can see p2.  Try setting a background color for each p1 and p2 and see if you are in fact NOT seeing p2.  9/10 of the time the reason will have been due to a view being initiated without a frame.  Double check that.